# Python NLP to Extract Fist Paragraph from a sentence

Tags: python, nlp

I have a usecase where i need to extract first paragraph from a long text.

Need to know is it possible to do it in NLP using python?

Any plugin support available ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a plugin for this. Depending on how your text is stored, a paragraph is either denoted by 1 enter `\n` or 2 enters `\n\n`. Beyond this, the question is if your text is stored in a fire, if you have read it in as a string.

if a string:

```
paragraph = text.split(sep)[0]
```

where sep is either `\n` or `\n\n` as appropriate

if it is stored as a file, if your separator is `\n`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    paragraph = f.readline()
```

if it is stored as a file, if your separator is `\n\n`, you actually need more than a single line:

```
paragraph = ''
with open(filename) as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line == '\n':
            break
        paragraph += line.strip('\n')
```

Comment: My text is present in elasticsearch and i need to read the whole text and capture the first paragraph alone. I will try with the above option.